# Conference Travel Grant

Tags: conference, research-undergraduate, travel

I am an undergraduate student from Bangladesh. Two of my posters have been accepted at Sigmod undergraduate research poster competition.

Now, I am looking forward to attend Sigmod. I will be receiving some travel grant from Sigmod to attend the event. However, the fund seems insufficient as the airfare from my country to US is very high.

**Is there any external source where I can apply for travel grants or support of similar kind?**

I am determined about attending Sigmod and I will be paying the rest of the costs by myself. So it would be really helpful for me if I get some support.

N.B. : I have already seen the post [Travel grant for undergraduate researcher for attending conference](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9729/travel-grant-for-undergraduate-researcher-for-attending-conference). However, I believe I need some more concrete answers. Thank you for understanding.

I have already asked the chairs for student volunteering and others. In this case, SIG and conference funding is basically the same. So I do not have the option to apply for SIGs.

Comment: Your question still seems very close to the one that you cited, which also seems to contain rather concrete answers also applicable to you (such as: see if you can become a student volunteer, etc.). I will vote to close this as a duplicate. If you have added information that makes clear why you think your question is different, please edit your question.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the given answers do not help me in general. It will be great if I can find a more concrete source of grants, where I can apply.

Comment: Are there any local organizations in Bangladesh that give funding for conferences?

Comment: OP, this may seem a bit silly to ask, but have you asked Sigmod for extra funding? I have known many a grad student that doesn't ask and then doesn't go because he/she does not have enough funding. Some conferences have leftover money they're willing to burn if there's demonstrated need. Talk to the organizers and they might be able to give you some extra money! :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, my country does not have any organization that funds computer science research.

Comment: I have asked the chairs of my track. I actually emphasized on my needs. Being an undergraduate, its really tough for me to bear such high costs. I am trying my best. Having a little support can ease my burden. Should I contact anyone else from the committee (e.g., sponsor chair)?